# Не могу передать данные через link_to (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста как можно передать параметр через link_to.
Нашел тут на сайте примеры, но у меня не вышло.
Задача такова: Есть календарь, там ссылки на сеансы с указанным временем сеанса:

```
<% session_time = SessionTime.find(id = @time_id).session_time  %>
  <li><%= link_to session_time, film_session,
          { :session_time => session_time } %></li>
```

В контроллере ловлю:

```
@session_time = params[:session_time]
```

Но если пытаюсь вывести в консоли значение параметра, получаю пустую строку.

Comment: Так а какая разметка генерится в результате, посмотрели? В документацию глянули?

Comment: Вот что генерится <a session_time="9.00" href="/film_sessions/1"> 9.00 </a>. В документацию смотрю, но не выходит найти решение.

Comment: <% puts params[:session_time].inspect %> - выдает nil

Comment: Так вы где-то видите **в самой ссылке** указание `session_time`?

Comment: Перефразируйте пожалуйста вопрос, не совсем понял в чем он заключается ) В моем понимании в первой строчке я получаю переменную с определенным значением. Далее в ссылке создаю параметр с названием  :session_time и передаю ему значение этой переменной. Далее в контроллере принимаю этот параметр.
Может я не правильно понимаю как это работает?

Comment: Вы знаете, как работает тег `<a>`? :)

Comment: До этого думал что понимаю))
Хмм, тег <a> формирует ссылку на нужную страницу с нужным названием!? Или вы не то имеете ввиду?)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39853/discussion-between-d-side-and-maxim-cherevatov).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась таким образом:

```
<li> <%= link_to session_time, film_session_path (:session_time=>session_time,:day=>date, :id=>film_session.id) %> </li>
```

Comment: Рекомендую прочитать [документацию к `url_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/UrlFor.html#method-i-url_for), а не городить такие ужасти.

Comment: @D-side документацию почитаю, спасибо. Но такое решение есть тут http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124862/link-to-send-parameters-along-with-the-url-and-grab-them-on-target-page и судя по количеству позитивных оценок предположил что оно подходит.

Comment: Там нет интерполяции, ссылка захардкожена. Интерполяция произвольной строки требует экранирования.

Comment: Скажите, так лучше?                       
<li>
<%= link_to session_time, film_session_path (:session_time=>session_time,:day=>date, :id=>film_session.id)  %>
</li>

Comment: Да, намного, вышеозначенный косяк это исправляет. Но можно ещё немножечко проще :) Модель можно воткнуть первым аргументом без ключа. Ссылка, в конечном счёте, на её страницу.

Comment: Хех,значит задачу можно решать несколькими путями.
Подскажите ещё пожалуйста, реально ли скрывать эти данные. Когда я перехожу по ссылке, то в адресной строке такие параметры отображаются и выходит, что злоумышленник может ввести свои данные: /film_sessions/3?day=2016-05-18&session_time=9.00 . Есть механизмы для скрытия этих параметров?)

Comment: Есть. Шифрование. Вшивать значения, сгенерировать и понять которые может только сервер. Но проще валидировать и отвергать кривые значения.

Comment: Ага, так и думал, но надеялся что есть ещё более простое решение. Спасибо)

Comment: Любое сложное решение можно запаковать в простую в использовании обёртку. Да сами рельсы это фантик в фантике.